# How to downgrade Realm Java from 2.x to 1.2.0?

Tags: android, realm

I've been trying to downgrade Realm from newer version 2.x to an older 1.2.0.

However, I'm getting this error when trying to build:

```
./app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/io/realm/HealthTeamRealmProxy.java
Error:(9, 25) error: cannot find symbol class ImplicitTransaction
```

Refering to class `io.realm.internal.ImplicitTransaction`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to clean + rebuild

Comment: I've done it already and even cleared gradle cache. Still, I get the same error.

Comment: Then please show your gradle dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to make it work!

First, I looked up for any file that mention realm-gradle-plugin version by using `grep`:

```
cd project/folder
grep -r '2\.2\.1' .
```

Then I got these locations and deleted them after closing Android Studio:

- app/build
- app/app.iml
- .gradle
- .idea

Finally, I reopened Android Studio + project and resynced. It worked perfectly.

Thanks EpicPandaForce for trying to help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry Sedir, I have the same problem, I'm trying to downgrade realm from version 2.2.1 to version 1.2.0 and I've the same error regarding io.realm.internal.ImplicitTransaction. I tried to use your solution but it didn't work, i can't compile. Can you provide some additional information?